# Official-shaped announcement: Sci-Fi & Fantasy Facebook page!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In case you haven't noticed yet, there's a shiny new addition to the [Stack Exchange Facebook family](http://www.facebook.com/stackexchange):

[**The Science Fiction & Fantasy Facebook Page**](http://www.facebook.com/scifi.SE)

Yeah! So I know you're thinking, "whaaat who caaaares why"? Here is the what AND the why:

- SciFi.SE has shown a super healthy growth pattern since its launch and we're attracting a lot of new users (this [question about the post-credits scene in *Avengers*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15454/who-is-in-the-post-credits-scene-of-the-avengers-movie) has amassed 25K views in a month, you guys)
- We want to encourage growth by taking the highlights of the Sci-Fi and Fantasy site and putting them in a social network-type situation, thus making them easily shareable and thus introducing more people to the site
- We want to also post relevant breaking news and announcements about science fiction and fantasy movies, television shows, books, games, comics, etc., with additional links to relevant tags/questions on our site
- This gives us another avenue to officially share items in our library that pertain to current events ("Game of Thrones" questions on Mondays, questions about franchises on their new film's opening day, etc.)

The goal is to post 3-4 questions from our site a day as well as news. This page is managed by me, personally, and is very much official. It's *so* run by me that if you leave suggestions of items to include, they might make their way to the page. There is no middle man! Or, the internet is the middle man.

The heart of this whole initiative is this: there's an entire world of science fiction and fantasy fandom on Facebook, an entire world that does not know this site exists. I hope to be able to get the word out and get them to this site. The easiest way to do that is to have an actual page for these mythical New Users to see in their feed, check out, 'like' and then have the Stack Exchange experience integrated into their online life. People have varied internet habits and some people are just not going to make checking our home page a regular priority. 'Liking' us gets a version of our home page integrated into their Facebook news feed.

So please, if you are so inclined, please ['like' the page on Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/scifi.SE) and share the news and questions that have already been posted or are going to be posted in the future. Thanks! Let's take over the world together!

Comment: If anyone has a particular question or blog post from this site they'd like to see shared by the official page, you can use [this form](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dEM0RjNXT3hpZUNpRFZaU2ZqSGpQb0E6MQ) to submit it, too, if you're into the filling-out-forms thing. :)

Comment: What, no being all geeky and all and going Google+? :)

Comment: @DVK They want people to actually **see** the posts. Anyone with Google+ likely already knows what StackExchange is lol.

Comment: @DVK haha YAY GOOGLE+. Google+ is cool ^_^

Comment: Facebook? WTF is that?

Comment: @User14111 - Never heard of it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the SFF:SE Facebook page is non-existent.

Comment: @Valorum Now that the question is closed, should we delete it (for the same reason)?

Comment: @Skooba - I think we should.

Answer (score 4):

**I've just checked it (by clicking the link) and it doesn't appear to be working.**

Also, can we please get an official SFF:SE MySpace page and a Second Life page as well? I'd hate to think we were missing out on the social network revolution.

Comment: No, seriously, I get a big bandaged thumbs-up following the links which says that the page is not working...

Comment: I'm intrigued why people are downvoting this. Are they not aware of the enormous potential of MySpace?

Comment: I heard there's some Sci Fi account on Twitter too.

Comment: @b_jonas - What the hell is Twitter? Now you're just making up silly names